# Error in resolving dependecies while using mikepenz/MaterialDrawer library

Tags: android, gradle, materialdrawer

I am getting the following errors while using the library:

> C:\ASP\example\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
>   Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>   Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Aayush Karwatkar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

The Build.Gradle file is like this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aayush.com.example"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

//Core card library
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.1.0'
//Optional for built-in cards
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-cards:2.1.0'
//Optional for RecyclerView
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-recyclerview:2.1.0'

compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.0.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You fix this error by changing your `compileSdkVersion`to `23`.